Are these shelves installed properly, or are they damaging the drywall?
We hired a handy person to mount some IKEA wall shelving a week ago. We haven't put anything on the shelves yet because the drywall around some of the screws appears to be bubbling/flaking. Not all, but some. (Potentially important context: we painted this room a couple days before shelf installation.)
Is this just the new paint chipping off, or are the screws coming out?
 

It seems that the person tightened the screws too hard, and the drywall anchor is coming through the drywall. This could cause the shelf to fall. You need to either use drywall anchors with a larger surface area, eg toggle bolts, or better, anchor the shelf to the studs.

It is likely that the screws are pulling the drywall anchor too hard.
There is another possibility; the paint was not adhered very well and the screw pulled away the paint from the wall as it threaded in.
You can tell by touching it. If it is paint only, it will feel like a bubble and easily push in with almost no effort and basically only where your finger is. If the drywall has been pulled out, it will push in with effort but will move the entire area in.
